# Removing path traversal of includes on CMake and QT

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to setup some include paths using CMake and QT Creator and I'd like to get the rid of the path traversal on my includes. What I meant by that is below.

```
#include <QtTest>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include "../../../../UI/Controller/PageNavigator/PageNavigatorPT.h"  //this works
//#include "PageNavigatorPT.h" // but this what I want
```

I want what is commented out, so I avoid these huge path traversals on my source. I added this to my cmake to try to fix the issue:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


add_executable(pageNavigatorTest
    ../../../../UI/Controller/PageNavigator/PageNavigatorBase.cpp
    ../../../../UI/Controller/PageNavigator/PageNavigatorPT.cpp
    tst_pagenavigatortest.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
PUBLIC
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}../../../../UI/Controller/PageNavigator
)


add_test(NAME pageNavigatorTest COMMAND pageNavigatorTest)
```

but it does not work. I still have to spell out the full path traversal.

Is there a way to make CMake make my source find the correct header by just writing:

```
#include "PageNavigatorPT.h" // but this what I want
```

Comment: I think in ``target_include_directories`` you need to use the name of the target, which is ``pageNavigatorTest`` in this case.

Comment: The path `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}../../../../UI/Controller/PageNavigator` misses **slash** after the first component `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`. BTW, you could print the final path with `message` command and examine printed path using `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Tsyvarev, this solved the problem (slash in front of the first dir

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
PUBLIC
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../UI/Controller/PageNavigator
)
```